# What's idiomatic way to decorate set of methods in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, compilation, decorator, aop

Python programmer getting familiar with static compilation world of java/kotlin is here. Here is a problem I'm trying to solve. I have a web-service client which provides bunch of methods to interact with this service, something like this:

```
class WebServiceClient {
  fun createUser(name: String, age: Int) {
    // Implementation
  }

  fun deleteUser(id: Int) {
    // Implementation
  }

  fun updateUser(id: Int, name: String, age: Int) {
    // Implementation
  }

  // And many more other methods
}
```

I would like to add logging functionality to some of these methods. Most straight-forward approach would be to modify every method explicitly:

```
...
  fun createUser(name: String, age: int) {
    log.info("before implementation")
    // Implementation
    log.info("after implementation")
  }
  
  fun deleteUser(id: Int) {
    log.info("before implementation")
    // Implementation
    log.info(after implementation")
  }
...
```

But this approach usually introduces duplication, boilerplate and clutters methods business logic with something unrelated (anti-AOP approach). Another way to solve it would be decorator and it would be easy to do it in python, though I don't have idea how to do it properly in Kotlin without introducing duplication and keeping logging logic separately from business logic of a method.

I tried to come up with higher order function which takes client method and its params, it's not exactly decorator, but follows the idea of not introducing duplicate code. Here is example:

```
class WebServiceClient {
  fun createUser(name: String, age: Int) {
  }

  ...
  private fun <T> decorator(action: (vararg args: Any) -> T, vararg args: Any) : T {
    log.info("before action")
    val result = action(*args)
    log.info("after action")
    return result
  }
}
```

But I ended up with bunch of compilation errors, like:

- **Unsupported [modifier on parameter in function type]** - for vararg in action type definition
- **The spread operator (*foo) may only be applied in a vararg position** - for calling action(*args)

Either there is no way to define such generic function in Kotlin or I don't know how to properly use Kotlin type system to define it. Moreover, maybe it's not the Kotlin way at all.

I didn't delve into annotations and reflection yet, because it sounds too complex to define such a simple thing (looking back to python way to do it), but maybe that's the only right direction to solve the problem.

What would be a Kotlin way to solve my problem, while avoiding duplication and following AOP principles (Aspect-oriented programming)?

Comment: As you were asking about AOP, I can recommend AspectJ and an approach that will work with Kotlin code, too, called post-compile-time weaving or simply binary weaving. That can be done both from Maven (AspectJ Maven Plugin) and Gradle (Freefair). The advantage is that your core code can be completely oblivious to the presence of any aspects.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted just to be sure that there is no simpler way to do it in Kotlin, while getting similar power and simplicity as in dynamic languages. But, I guess AOP in Java/Kotlin requires way more effort (amount of code and learning curve) than in dynamic languages

Comment: Well, if you want no learning curve, maybe stick with Python then. As for whether there is a more canonical way to solve this directly in Kotlin without AspectJ, I cannot say, because I do not speak Kotlin. But learning AspectJ is certainly possible, and binary weaving works for any JVM language. Compile-time weaving is only implemented for Java, as the AspectJ native syntax is a superset of Java. AspectJ certainly is the most mature and efficient (performance-wise) AOP implementation on the maket, probably even beyond the JVM ecosystem, including Python.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you just want to extract the logging logic into another function.

Your `decorator` method is nearly there. The method doesn't actually need to take any parameters, and you can `inline` the whole thing, so that no lambda objects are actually created. It compiles to exactly the same thing as if you wrote the `log.info` calls inline.

```
private inline fun <T> withLogging(action: () -> T) : T {
    log.info("before action")
    val result = action()
    log.info("after action")
    return result
}
```

Usage:

```
class User

class WebServiceClient {
    // here is a demonstration for a non-Unit method
    fun createUser(name: String, age: Int): User = withLogging {
        // create a user here...
        // you can access the name and age parameters here
        // withLogging returns whatever the lambda returns
        User()
    }
    
    // Unit methods work just as well
    fun doSomeSideEffect() = withLogging {
        println("Side effect")
    }
}
```

---

If you want to generate code in a more complex way, have a look at [Kotlin Symbol Processing](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/ksp-overview.html). This allows you to write your own annotation processor.

```
// your annotation processor would see this annotation, and insert log.info calls appropriately
@Logged
fun createUser(name: String, age: Int): User {
    // create a user here...
    return User()
}
```

I wouldn't use this when an inline function can do the job though.

Comment: That's definitely looks similar to what I thought. I came up with something close to your example but without inline, thus I wasn't sure about runtime efficiency for passing lambda around, but your version is even better. With this implementation I have only two small concerns:

1) How to combine multiple decorators if there is need? I guess just write nested lambdas in a similar way

2) I can't use return statement in decorated functions (with some exceptions), because it became a lambda now. Not a big deal, but method definition feels a little bit DSL-ish

Comment: In the end I guess it's the best available option before diving deep into annotation processing

Comment: @sunprophit For 2), you can still use a labelled return statement if you label the lambda itself. See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/returns.html#return-to-labels

Comment: Is there a way to access 1) name of the decorated method in decorating function? 2) name of the class where decorated method is define? I only see an option to pass it explicitly as a string to decorator function

Comment: @sunprophit You can get the name of the class by making it an extension function on `Any`, and getting `this::class.simpleName`  (or `qualifiedName`). You can get the function name from inspecting the call stack, but only if it is not `inline`. Either way, if you need to do this, it is likely this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), or you need annotation processing.

Comment: @sunprophit I would suggest that you post a new question, if this is indeed an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: It's still related to decorator pattern and how to get properties and behaviour similar to dynamic languages, like in python. There are just multiple aspects of this problem 1) how to decorate your methods with auxiliary functionality 2) how to not bloat decorated function with decorator logic to follow encapsulation principles 3) how to refer to decorated entity in decorator logic: class reference, method reference or method input parameters 4) how to do it in the way when single decorator implementation could be used for decorating multiple classes

Comment: I guess, it's not possible to come up with all details, before you started to understand some target platform (kotlin/java/jvm) limitations. My question is not even about writing a decorator for a specific function, but more about what the ways are to decorate your logic in Kotlin and how closely you can get to python's flexibility while still writing idiomatic Kotlin code. Maybe it made sense to define even broader scope for a question

Comment: @sunprophit That's way too many aspects for a Stack Overflow question. I would suggest that you break it down into smaller questions and ask them separately. That said, I feel like you are trying too hard to achieve Python features in Kotlin. Don't think about Python at all - start with an actual practical problem, like your logging question here, not "how to do python decorators" (which is an XY problem). Then try to solve that.

Comment: IMO, this is not a good AOP replacement, because you still need to explicitly call the logging functionality. With AOP, you model your aspect separately. The target application works without the aspect and is oblivious to its existence. The aspect is woven into the application in the appropriate places by means of pointcuts specifiers. I am not criticising your pure AOP Kotlin approach as such here, it is working fine. It just is not a clear separation of cross-cutting concerns from core code as AOP enables you to use.